# Trac Setup Error

Tags: setup, tracker

I'm trying to setup the trac, this is the commands that I used:

```
sudo apt-get install trac python-setuptools libapache2-mod-python enscript

sudo mkdir /var/www/trac
sudo trac-admin /var/www/trac/repos initenv
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/bin/trac-admin", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2659, in <module>
    parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 546, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: Trac==0.12.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously `trac-admin` requires `Trac==0.12.2`. The trac version in the ubuntu natty repositories is 0.11.7-4 ([trac ubuntu package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/+source/trac)).

You could try to install trac 0.12.2 in natty using `easy_install`. That's a python module that lets you automatically download, build, install, and manage Python packages.

So try:

```
sudo easy_install Trac==0.12.2
```